# Cannot set a style property with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm performing some operations on a chart which must have a part hidden while an operation is done and after that it must be visible again.

In order to do so I'm setting the display to none (which works fine) like this:

```
myProp = d3.select(".my-column");
myProp.style("display", "none");
```

If it is checked it shows the wanted result:

```
console.log(myProp.style("display")); //-> "none"
```

The problem comes out when I want to change it to visible/initial:

```
myProp.style("display", "visible");
```

It doesn't work, the console.log returns `none` as before. Why does this happen and how can it be set to visible/initial?

Comment: There's no value as "visible" for the **display** property. Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display (Initial value is **inline**, so if you changed it to "initial", it'd show "inline")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the initial value of display was not `visible` or `initial` as I was expecting but `inline`.

In this case if it is tried to change it from none to inline it works.

```
myProp.style("display", "inline"); //-> "inline"
```

Probably it cannot change it to other options, not sure.

Comment: It can be changed to any *valid* option. If you try to set it to something invalid, like `visible` or `hidden` or `banana`, it won't work.